# How to use embedded View Models

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I may well be over complicating this. I have read several tutorials now but don't understand something.

I understood that an observable collection was mapped to a list of model items.

```
Model
    List family

View model
     Observable collection families(model.families)
```

But I now read two things:

1. A data context **always** points to a view model object.
2. A observable collection should be a collection of **view models**

Hence my confusion. If the combo box on the view is bound to the list of families, and then as a family is selected the rest of the controls are for details of that family ...

I understand the concept of the view model properties role is the mechanism between model data and view data. And that each property raises onpropertychanged.

But if your model has a list of family objects, how do you construct a observable collection of familyviewmodels?

If there is a more appropriate place to ask this then kindly direct me and I will remove the question.

I thought `ObservableCollection (model.families)` was the right thing. And then bind values to members of the selected combo object. It certainly works. But from what I have read I feel I have something not right as detailed above.

Thank you for easing my headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me your question is at least partially "opinion based". As such, you might have better luck soliciting input on http://programmers.stackexchange.com or http://codereview.stackexchange.com. Note that if you opt for the latter, you *must* construct a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates your question, and present your question in relation to that code example.

> But if your model has a list of family objects, how do you construct a observable collection of familyviewmodels?

You haven't offered anything in the way of a code example here so it's impossible to give any precise guidance. However, there's certainly nothing stopping you from creating a `FamilyViewModel` that proxies a `Family` object, just as your `ObservableCollection<Family>` would proxy a list of `Family` objects. Then you can use `ObservableCollection<FamilyViewModel>` instead.

That's the extent of a "practical programming problem" as I see presented in your question, i.e. that would make it on-topic here. That said, as long as I'm commenting, I'll point out that design patterns are intended to make the code easier to write and to maintain. If you find that attempting to follow a dogma imposed by a design pattern is getting in the way of good, maintainable code, then it's time to let go of that particular dogma, at least for that particular moment.

In particular, I have found that the line between "view model" and "model" can be blurry. In some cases, a program is primarily about the interaction with the user, and the view model is all that's needed. In other cases, the program is mainly business logic and writing a whole new view model just to wrap an existing business-logic data structure is overkill.

The separation of concerns can be useful, e.g. when you need to interact with other components that need to be completely free of the UI, or you want to be able to test UI code without being tied to some expensive and hard-to-recreate business-logic data structure. But don't let the concept tie your hands. If you have a simple data structure that can be easily mapped directly to UI elements via e.g. a template for a list-based control, I don't see anything wrong with using that data structure directly as your "view model".

Noting, of course, there are those who would disagree with my position, and in some cases vehemently. Hence the "opinion based" nature of your question. It's arguably the kind of question that would be closed here. IMHO, if you want better and more objective responses, you should present your question with a good MCVE, and focus your question on some *specific* aspect of that code example that can be addressed in an objective way (e.g. such as the question about how to map your business logic data structures to a view-model-compatible data structure).